# How to execute URL in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

I want to send the SMS to the user using the third party API key in codeigniter. For that I used the `file_get_content()` But when file runs it takes the more execution time and after display blank page. 
I also use CURL but same error in codeignator.

This code runs another PHP script only error in codeigniter
Following my code:

```
$to = "thisisprashantkumbhar";
$username ='puretechnology';
$numbers = '9326447272';
$messagenew=rawurlencode($to);
$apikey = 'gdfgrte5-er54-h57f-4rgt-0a7215d15abc';
$url = "http://sms1.businesslead.co.in/sendSMS?username=$username&message=$messagenew&sendername=CMISAM&smstype=TRANS&numbers=$numbers&apikey=$apikey";
$response = file_get_contents($url);
return $response;
```

Comment: try **echo $response;**

Comment: yes I was but nothing prints anything

Comment: try something like: **if(!$response or empty($response))echo 'NO or empty response. '**

Answer (score 1):

```
  $stream_options = array(
    'http' => array(
       'method'  => 'GET',
    ),
);
     $context  = stream_context_create($stream_options);
     $response = file_get_contents("http://api.smsbrain.in/1.2/appsms/send.php?user=username&passwd=141414&senderId=SATISH&recipients=9723613143&message=Hello", null, $context);


    echo json_encode($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

echo $url and it will show you the complete url then execute url you will get the error. e.g invalid key check your details as well.